# excel VBA to add conditional format that adds border to cells below

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have written some code to add borders to the next row but using the offset method is causing an error. my code is below

```
Dim newCondition6 As FormatCondition
Set newCondition6 = Range("G24:J60").FormatConditions.Add( _
                     Type:=xlExpression, _
                     Formula1:= _
                       "=(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,1,""Main Details"")) <> INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,1,""Main_Details"")))")

With newCondition6
  .SetFirstPriority
  With Range.Offset(1, 0).Borders
  .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
        End With
  With Range.Offset(1, 1).Borders
  .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
        End With
  .StopIfTrue = False
End With
With Range.Offset(1, 2).Borders
  .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
        End With
With Range.Offset(1, 3).Borders
  .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
        End With
```

Comment: a) how is that formula ever going to be true? b) how is that formula different from `='Main Details'!G24<>'Main Details'!G24` ?

Comment: sorry yes added the wrong formula , buit the error is using the offset as I need the row below to have the borders

Answer (score 2):

Your formula doesn't look like it will ever be true.

Once you get that sorted, you go 'off the range' by using an unqualified Range object and Offset. If you need to add borders to the row below, then add them to the row below directly and reference the cells above that row in the formula.

```
Sub AddBorders()

    With Worksheets("Sheet6").Range("G25:J60") '<~~ Add CFR starting in row 25
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="='Main Details'!G24<>'Main Details'!G24")  '<~~ FIX THIS FORMULA
            With .Borders
                .Color = vbBlack
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it is nearly working , but it seems to be only adding the Main Details'!G24<>'Main_Details'!G24 to every row. I need it so say row G30 had some text added/canged that was different to G30 on the other sheet then add the borders. at present all cells are linked to g24 being changed

Comment: Then the formula would be `Formula1:="=G24<>'Main Details'!G24")` You had each side of the `<>` referencing the same cell on the same worksheet. Like I said in my comments above, that would **never** be true.

Comment: is it possible to add the conditional format as secondary format as i have another conditionalformat that is set to turn the text red if not matched to another sheet , then to have a border added to the next empty row use the Formula1:="=G24<> "") . so if any text is added then the cell below will have borders added

Comment: delete or comment out `.FormatConditions.Delete`.